# Matching two data frames' columns and store it in new column

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames:

```
df:

id         id.1      weight
RoLu1976   Gr1969     50
MaRg1988   FuDa1989   10
FiKy1977   RoBa1983   12
MaTe1980   SeNd1998   23
Gr69       MaGe1977   72
```

And:

```
df1:

id         id.1
Gr1969     RoLu1976
FiKy1977   RoBa1983
```

I need to make a `weight` column in `df1` by matching `df1$id` and `df1$id.1` with `df$id` and `df$id.1`.

```
df1:

id         id.1      weight
Gr1969     RoLu1976   50
FiKy1977   RoBa1983   12
```

Sometimes the observations are **exchanged** in the columns, for example, `df's` first row and `df1's` first row:

```
df:
id        id.1     weight
Rolu1976  Gr1969   50
```

and

```
df1:
id       id.1
Gr1969   RoLu1976
```

It means that the column order doesn't matter for the matching.

**[EDIT]**

I try to do it with `inner_join` function from `dplyr` package, and `merge` function, but, it is necessary make all the combinations of the columns. 
There is a way to matching them without specify all the combinations?

Or there is a fastest way to do it with **python pandas module**?

Comment: just do a `merge` by the columns names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, if the interchange in the columns was intended or by mistake. Here is the solution

---

solution

```
rbind(merge(df1, df2, by.x = c('id.1','id'), by.y = c('id','id.1')),
merge(df1, df2, by.x = c('id.1','id'), by.y = c('id.1','id')))
```

---

output

```
      id.1       id weight
1   Gr1969 RoLu1976     50
2 RoBa1983 FiKy1977     12
```

---

data

```
 df1 <- read.table(text='id         id.1      weight
    RoLu1976   Gr1969     50
    MaRg1988   FuDa1989   10
    FiKy1977   RoBa1983   12
    MaTe1980   SeNd1998   23
    Gr69       MaGe1977   72', header=TRUE)


    df2 <- read.table(text='id         id.1
    Gr1969     RoLu1976
    FiKy1977   RoBa1983', header=TRUE)
```